# Replace all characters except ascii 32 to 127 and ascii 0, 13, 27 in postgres sql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, greenplum

Is there any function which can replace all characters except ascii 32 to 127 and ascii 0, 13, 27 in postgres sql. I do not want to replace spaces, line feeds etc. I want to replace weird characters like club signs, square or a weird asterisk.

I tried modifying regexp_replace like below but it is not working.

```
select regexp_replace('abc$wanto&tore9046move#special~04 chars', '[^\x00-\x7f]', '', 'g') 
--This is giving error ERROR: 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

select *, regexp_replace('abc$wanto&tore9046move#special~04 chars', '[^[:ascii:]]', '', 'g')
--This one is taking everything beyond 255 also in the set.
```

Thanks much for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unicode range:

```
select regexp_replace('abc$wanto&tore9046move#special~04 chars', '[\u0080-\u00ff]', '', 'g')
```

[Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

This will remove any character in `128-255` ascii range.

Comment: Square and asterisk is within `1-127` range hence won't be replaced using above.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not know that. Thank you. I corrected my question. : ).

Answer (score 2):

You were almost right with:

```
select regexp_replace('abc$wanto&tore9046move#special~04 chars', '[^\x00-\x7f]', '', 'g')
```

but the null byte `\x00` is not valid in PostgreSQL string literals, so you'd have to start at `\x01`. Your desired range starts at 32 (0x20), so use that plus a few specific inclusions for 13 (0x0d) and 27 (0x1b):

```
select regexp_replace('abc$wanto&tore9046move#special~04 chars', '[^\x20-\x7f\x0d\x1b]', '', 'g')
```

or, with a more useful input:

```
regress=> select regexp_replace('aáiï*∞ıb ', '[^\x20-\x7f\x0d\x1b]', '', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 ai*b 
(1 row)
```

Comment: That last regex is the only one that really does the job that is likely needed since the others assume there are no non-printable characters in the lower range, which isn't accurate.